# Sum variables group with specific character value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that look like this

```
                variable value flag
1            a_b_table_m 0.010  yes
2            a_b_chair_t 0.020   no
3             a_b_desk_m 0.011  yes
4             a_b_desk_t 0.120   no
5            a_b_table_t 0.050  yes
6  a_c_desk_table_sofa_m 0.060   no
7             a_c_sofa_m 0.080  yes
8            a_b_chair_m 0.040   no
9            a_a_stool_m 0.050  yes
10     a_a_stool_chair_m 0.020   no
```

I want to

i) group the data by flag and variable and sum by value

ii) add the values of standalone variables, for example `a_b_table_m` and `a_b_table_m` are added,  `a_b_chair_t`, `a_b_chair_m`, and `a_a_stool_chair_m` are together based on their flag. Similarly, `a_b_desk_t`  and `a_c_desk_table_sofa_m` are added together.

The first problem maybe solved using the following data and code

```
df <- data.frame(variable = c('a_b_table_m', 'a_b_chair_t', 'a_b_desk_m','a_b_desk_t','a_b_table_t', 'a_c_desk_table_sofa_m', 'a_c_sofa_m', 'a_b_chair_m', 'a_a_stool_m', 'a_a_stool_chair_m'), value = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.011, 0.12, 0.05, 0.06, 0.08, 0.04, 0.05, 0.02), flag = c('yes', 'no'))
```

---

```
df %>% 
mutate(cat = gsub('a_b_|_m|a_a_|a_c_|_t$', '', variable)) %>% 
group_by(flag, cat) %>% 
summarise(total_value = sum(value))
```

I am expecting the output will look like this

```
                 variable value flag   cat               total_value
1            a_b_table_m 0.010  yes   table              0.06
2            a_b_chair_t 0.020   no   chair              0.08
3             a_b_desk_m 0.011  yes   desk               0.011
4             a_b_desk_t 0.120   no   desk               0.18
5            a_b_table_t 0.050  yes   table              0.06
6  a_c_desk_table_sofa_m 0.060   no   desk_table_sofa    0.18
7             a_c_sofa_m 0.080  yes   sofa               0.08
8            a_b_chair_m 0.040   no   chair              0.08
9            a_a_stool_m 0.050  yes   stool              0.05
10     a_a_stool_chair_m 0.020   no   stool_chair        0.08
```

I appreciate any suggestions for the second problem.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @Sotos please see the edited question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `mutate` instead of `summarise` in your second code block your desired output is generated:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(cat = gsub('a_b_|_m|a_a_|a_c_|_t$', '', variable)) %>% 
  group_by(flag, cat) %>% 
  mutate(total_value = sum(value))
```

While `summarise` will only let grouping columns and the summarised value-columns persist, `mutate` just matches the value to every row in the group.

Comment: The output of second entry should be 0.08 `(0.02 (a_b_chair_t) + 0. 04 (a_b_chair_m)  +  0.02 (a_a_stool_chair_m ))`, the same applies to 4th entry `(0.12 (a_b_desk_t) +   0.06 (a_c_desk_table_sofa_m) )`.